# How to preview email using AWS SES (aws-sdk-ses) in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, actionmailer, preview

I am working on Ruby on Rails applications. We choose the AWS SES service to send emails to our users. We are using the `aws-sdk-ses` gem for this purpose.
And I'm faced with a problem with previewing emails.
My user_mailer.rb has the next code:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  layout 'mailer'

  def invite
    invitation = params[:invitation]
    email = invitation.email
    subject = 'Invitation email'

    # The HTML body of the email
    htmlbody = render_to_string(
      template: 'user_mailer/invite',
      layout: true,
      locals: {
        email: receiver_email,
      }
    )
    send_email(
       receiver: receiver_email,
       sender: 'default@email.com',
       subject: subject,
       body: htmlbody
    )
  end

  def send_email(receiver:, sender:, subject:, body:)
    AWS_SES_CLIENT.send_email(
      {
        destination: { to_addresses: [receiver] },
        message: {
          body: {
            html: { charset: 'UTF-8',
                    data: body }
          },
          subject: {
            charset: 'UTF-8',
            data: subject
          }
        },
        source: sender
      }
    )
  rescue Aws::SES::Errors::ServiceError => e
    Rails.logger.info "ERROR! Email for #{receiver} with subject #{subject} wasn't sent with error message: #{e}"
  end
end
```

And my `spec/mailers/preview/user_mailer_preview.rb` has the next code:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

# Preview all emails at http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/user_mailer
class UserMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  def invite
    UserMailer.with(invitation: UserInvitation.first).invite
  end
end
```

But when I go to the `http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/user_mailer` I see the message

> You are trying to preview an email that does not have any content.
> This is probably because the **mail** method has not been called in
> **user_mailer#invite.**

I suggest that standard Rails previewer track the calling the **mail** method, but I'm used custom **send_email** method to send email. So it doesn't work. I'm trying to find the solution on the AWS SDK guide but I didn't. I suppose it needs to reconfigure action_mailer in some way.

Comment: any luck with this? Having the same issue and this is the only result when you google this error